# How do you pass a 2d array of strings to a function in C language?

Tags: c, arrays

I can't figure out how to pass `radjectives` (2D array of strings) to `randomizeadj` function.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<ctype.h>

char randomizenouns(char[][]);
char randomizeadj(char[][]);

int main() // beginning of program.
{
  int a=0, b=0;
  char *answers[5]={'\0'};
  char *rnouns[3][10]={'\0'};
  char *radjectives[2][17]={'\0'};
  char *rcolors[11]={'\0'};

  radjectives[0][0]="intriguing";
  // ...
  radjectives[1][6]="loud";

  rnouns[0][0]="puppies";
  // ...
  rnouns[1][9]="people";

  rcolors[0]="black";
  // ...
  rcolors[10]="orange";

  { srand(time(NULL));

  printf("\n\tProgram Paragrahs\n");
  printf("\tFor this program you will answer several questions which will then be used to     conjure a random story the length of a paragraph.Please Keep your answers clean.Enjoy\n");

  printf("\nWhat is your name?");
  scanf("%s\n",answers[0]);
  printf("\nWhat is your favorite book?");
  scanf("%s",answers[1]);
  printf("\nWhat is your favorite color?");
  scanf("%s",answers[2]);
  printf("\nWhat city do you live in?");
  scanf("%s",answers[3]);
  printf("\nWhat car do you drive?");
  scanf("%s",answers[4]);
```

---

**Right here is where I get lost** - I cannot figure out how to pass the `radjectives` array to the `randomizeadj` function.

```
  printf("%s gets lost in their %s %s.\n",answers[0],randomizeadj(radjectives[a][b]),answers[1]);
  printf("%s loves to play with %s %s.\n",answers[0],rcolors[(rand()    %11)],randomizenouns(rnouns[a][b]);.
  printf("%s lives in a(n) %s %s.\n",answers[0],randomizeadj(radjectives[a][b]),answers[3]);
  printf("While living in %s %s drives a(n) %s %s.\n",answers[3],answers[0],rcolors[(rand() %11)],answers[4]);
  printf("%s is a(n) %s person who likes the color  %s.\n",answers[0],randomizeadj(radjectives[a][b]),answers[2]);
} // end of program

char randomizenouns(char nouns[x][y]);
{
     int x=(rand() %3);
     int y=(rand() %10);

     char randomnoun= nouns[x][y];

     return randomnoun;
}

char randomizeadj(char adjectives[x][y]);
{
     int x=(rand() %2);
     int y=(rand() %7);

     char randomadjective= adjectives[x][y];

     return randomadjective;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
randomizeadj(radjectives);
```

e.g.

```
char *adj = randomizeadj(radjectives);
printf(adj);
```

At the moment things won't compile, change both the declarations and definitions of the functions to:

```
char *randomizenouns(char *nouns[3][10]);
char *randomizeadj(char *adjectives[2][17]);
```

or:

```
char *randomizenouns(char *nouns[][10]);
char *randomizeadj(char *adjectives[][17]);
```

Things I changed:

- Changed `char[][]` (a 2D array of characters) to a 2D array or character *pointers* (also note that the first dimension of an array must always have a length specified).
- Changed your functions to return `char *` rather than `char` (otherwise your function just returns a single character, rather than a string (but you still just `return adjectives[x][y]`).

Other things I changed:

Changed `answers` to not be an array of `char` pointers but rather a 2D array of `char`s, otherwise the compiler won't have memory assigned for the values you're trying to read in.

```
char answers[5][100];
```

There's also a `;` where there shouldn't be here: (for both functions)

```
char randomizeadj(char adjectives[x][y]);
{
  ...
```

[Test program](http://ideone.com/p5fOqp).

Comment: It still says incompatible pointer type I cant figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It says incompatible pointer type when I compile at the line where I am trying to use the function radomizeadj(radjectives) in the main body.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply pass it the way you have declared:

change your function definition and declaration to following:

```
 char *randomizenouns(char *nouns[rows][cols]) 
 char *randomizeadj(char *adjectives[rows][cols])
```

**Note**: for 2D array you need to pass `cols` size, so pass as required

**EDIT**

and in your code you have put semi-colon( ; ) in function defintion 
`char randomizeadj(char adjectives[x][y]); {  ... }`
`char randomizenouns(char nouns[x][y]); { .... }`
**remove semi-colon from function definition**

---

you were getting that `incompatible pointer type` error as earlier on you might **not** have changed the **function declaration signatures** with the **matching function definition signatures**.